# How is a string starting with R+ and ending with == encoded?

Tags: javascript, java, security, base64, local-storage

Rookie question. I have a value (email address - test data) stored in the browser localStorage and I need to decode it: "R+XKqPlFc2G6sUxdHWrEfg=="

It looks like a Base64 encoded string except for the R+ prefix. (As a result [`atob`](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_win_atob.asp) prints out a non meaningful result).

Is there a way to know which algorithm was used to encode it?

Comment: It's still base64 - there is a URL safe and a standard version.  In the standard version, the + symbol is used instead of - or _ (can't remember which!)

Comment: it's the unsafe url version but still I can't correctly decode the email address.. :(

Comment: Yep, `atob` and `btoa` don't work on standard base64.  You'll need to find another way

Comment: @LukeJoshuaPark I tried also with `java.util.Base64` but same result :(

Comment: There you have 128 bit of data. Maybe this is just a hash? MD5? `47e5caa8f9457361bab14c5d1d6ac47e` or an uuid `47e5caa8-f945-7361-bab1-4c5d1d6ac47e`

Comment: Do you know the decoded value? Or do you just know it's an email address?

Comment: @dpr I know that the original value is: testwh3@neo.com

Comment: Another encoded value coming from the same source is: "2VN4BD7Wf3ZA9lMfvasiPllF+D+pUs1aid8SO9/aoNg="